# How to get the values from JPanel components like drop down, text fields which are getting created on a fly

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a `JPanel` which consists of a dropdown and a text field inside my `JFrame`. There is a button in my `JFrame`, when user clicks on that button, application adds new `JPanel` with the same components i.e. drop down and a text field. So, for this I have created a function which gets called on clicking on the button using `ActionListener`.

Everything works fine from GUI side but the problem is when user is done with adding `JPanel`s and entering the values in these drop downs and text fields, it will click on Submit button. Upon clicking on Submit button, I should be able to fetch the values from all drop downs and text fields. This is a challenge, since I am using the same functions to create `JPanel`s, I can't call its name to get the values since that will give me the last `JPanel` values.

Any suggestion how I should go about this? I have added the screenshot of my `JFrame` and the function to create the `JPanel`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 public static void AddPanel(final Container pane) {

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    String text = "<html><b>Property" + nooftimes + " :</b></html>";
    JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
    panel1.add(label);

    panel1.add(new JLabel("Please enter the property"));
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
    model.addElement("value1");
    model.addElement("value2");
    model.addElement("value3");
    model.addElement("value4");
    model.addElement("value5");


    final JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>(model);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(comboBox1);
    comboBox1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 22));
    panel1.add(comboBox1);

    final JTextField txtfield1 = new JTextField(
            "Please enter your value here");
    txtfield1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 22));
    panel1.add(txtfield1);

    txtfield1.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            txtfield1.setText("");
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            // nothing
        }
    });
    container.add(panel1);
    nooftimes++;

    frame.revalidate();
    frame.validate();
    frame.repaint();
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image: **frame_screenshot**]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return the `JPanel` and store it in a `List<JPanel>`. When you click your submit-Button you are able to iterate through the `JPanel`s and its `Component`s.

```
public class Application {

    private static List<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<>();
    private static Container someContainer = new Container();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        panels.add(addPanel(someContainer));
        panels.add(addPanel(someContainer));
        panels.add(addPanel(someContainer));

        submit();
    }

    public static JPanel addPanel(final Container pane) {
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        // shortened code
        final JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>();
        panel1.add(comboBox1);

        final JTextField txtfield1 = new JTextField("Please enter your value here");
        txtfield1.setText(String.valueOf(Math.random()));
        panel1.add(txtfield1);
        return panel1;
    }

    private static void submit() {
        for (JPanel panel : panels) {
            Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
            for (Component comp : components) {
                // Cast comp to JComboBox / JTextField to get the values
                if (comp instanceof JTextField) {
                    JTextField textField = (JTextField) comp;
                    System.out.println(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the help. Your solution worked for me. I have accepted your answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply have a class (extending JPanel) with specific methods to add your components , and to get inputs from user (i.e. get the combo box selected index and text from textfield ).
Every time you add a panel, you don't call a static method, but you create an instance of this class, keeping the reference somewhere (for example adding it to an arraylist).

But you could consider a different scenario: personally i don't like to add components "on fly", you could have a component (for example another JComboBox), where user can select the number of values he needs.
You decide a default value (for example 4), so at the beginning you create 4 panels of your class, and you can use a simple array containing them.
If the user changes the number of panels, you could dispose frame and create a new one.
Of course this solution does not woork good if you want to keep inputs inserted, or if the frame construction takes a lot of time.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO8Zf.png) there is a screenshot of a gui i created: user can select the number of partials, when the choice changes i just recreate the panels below,containing the textfields (which are memorized in a two-dimensional array).

Comment: Thank you for providing the help. I have voted your answer as helpful.